# Mongoose JS findOne always returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been fighting with trying to get Mongoose to return data from my local MongoDB instance; I can run the same command in the MongoDB shell and I get results back. I have found a post on stackoverflow that talks about the exact problem I'm having [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089510/mongoose-js-queries-all-coming-back-null-or-empty); I've followed the answers on this post but I still can't seem to get it working. I created a simple project to try and get something simple working and here's the code.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var userSchema = new Schema({
    userId: Number,
    email: String,
    password: String,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    addresses: [
        {
            addressTypeId: Number,
            address: String,
            address2: String,
            city: String,
            state: String,
            zipCode: String
        }
    ],
    website: String,
    isEmailConfirmed: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    isActive: { type: Boolean, default: true },
    isLocked: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    roles: [{ roleName: String }],
    claims: [{ claimName: String, claimValue: String }]
});

var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/personalweb');
var userModel = mongoose.model('user', userSchema);

userModel.findOne({ email: 'test@test.com' }, function (error, user) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
    console.log("User: " + user);
});
```

And here is the response of the 2 console.log statements:

Error: null

User: null

When the connect method is called I see the connection being made to my Mongo instance but when the findOne command is issued nothing appears to happen. If I run the same command through the MongoDB shell I get the user record returned to me. Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Mongoose pluralizes the name of the model as it considers this good practice for a "collection" of things to be a pluralized name. This means that what you are currently looking for in code it a collection called "users" and not "user" as you might expect.

You can override this default behavior by specifying the specific name for the collection you want in the model definition:

```js
var userModel = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'user');
```

The third argument there is the collection name to be used rather than what will be determined based on the model name.

Comment: OK I tried this and I'm still getting null in my user variable. Is there anything other than stepping through the code line by line that I can do to debug what is going wrong?

Comment: @CodeMonkey What exactly are you doing in the "MongoDB shell"? The obvious call here was if you were not aware then the collection is pluralized by mongoose. The only other thing is that you are clearly not doing "the same thing" as you say.

Comment: The command I'm issuing through the Mongo shell is db.User.findOne({email: 'test@test.com'}); is this not the same command that mongoose is sending?

Comment: I got it to work...I needed to capitalize 'user'; after I did that it returned the results. Thanks for all of your help @Neil

Comment: Its not clear in docs. The kittens example is just a distraction.

Comment: I also face this same issue. But for me find({}) works fine.. This happens for me only with the graphql-scalars defined field (in gql schema I made a field of type emailaddress and defined it as string in mongoose schema. Only here this happens. But when I filter through some other field this works fine. I havent found any way in resolving this yet. Any suggestions?)

Answer (score 2):

I know 7 years pass, however I'm starting to develop in node JS with MongoDB using mongoose, so searching for solution to the same problem, *result = null*.
After read this post and all the answers, I release that I totally forget to include the **DB name** in the string of the connection, `'mongodb://localhost:27017/DB name'` so that solved my case. I guessed this can be help other clueless like me! :)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31437041)

Comment: Personally speaking, I found this answer brilliant.  I was having one of those developer blindness days and needed this reminder.