# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'save')

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Currently working on a discord js bot, where I am intending to add members into a particular channel. The command that I am using for the same is `!am @<user_id>`

Here is my addMember.js file

```
const channelModel = require("../models/channel.model");

module.exports = {
  name: "am",
  usage: "@<user> @<optional_user> ...",
  guildOnly: true,
  description: "Adds a new member to the standup",
  async execute(message, args) {
    if (!args.length)
      return message.channel.send(
        "Ruh Roh! You need to mention **_at least_** one member as argument!"
      );
    channelModel
      .findOne({channelId: message.channel.id})
      .then((channel) => {
        args.forEach((mention) => {
          if (mention.startsWith("<@") && mention.endsWith(">")) {
            mention = mention.slice(2, -1);

            if (mention.startsWith("!")) mention = mention.slice(1);
            const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(mention);

            if (member && channel.members.indexOf(member.id) == -1)
              channel.members.push(member.id);
          }
        });
        console.log(channel)
        channel
          .save()
          .then(() => message.channel.send("Members updated :tada:"))
          .catch((err) => {
            console.err(err);
            message.channel.send(
              "Oh no :scream:! An error occured somewhere in the matrix!"
            );
          });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
        message.channel.send(
          "Oh no :scream:! An error occured somewhere in the matrix!"
        );
      });
  },
};
```

And my model.js

```
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

const channelSchema = new Schema({
    serverId: String,
    channelId: String,
    members: [String]
  }, {timestamp: true})

module.exports = model("Channel", channelSchema);
```

Error seems to be occuring while using `.save()`(around line 32 where `channel` is returned as null

Comment: rather than `.findOne({ channelId: message.channel.id })` does `.findOne({ channelId: message.channelId })` work?

Comment: It means `channelModel.findOne({channelId: message.channel.id})` returns/resolves to `null`. Does any of these results help? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmongoose%5D+findone+returns+null

Comment: yes I got that it's not getting a proper return at line 17, `.findOne({ channelId: message.channelId })` seems to give the same error, I also tried with `.findById(message.channel.id)` but gives the same `null` return in every case.
Any suggestion to fix the same would be really appreciated.

Comment: what about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777952/14978104) ? so your model may actually be called `channels.model`